# SQL : Filtering with multiple columns in a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, correlated-subquery

I want to select all the rows from a table, those are not present in ID column of another table.

For example my **Table1** has below structure :

```
C1  C2  C3
--  --  --
1   A   Z
2   B   Y
3   C   X
```

My **Table2** Looks like :

```
    D1  D2  
    --  --  
    1   A   
    2   Y
    3   X
```

My working query looks something like :

```
slect * from Table1
where (C2 NOT IN (Select D2 from Table2);
```

This works fine, but if I want to filter on basis of combination of both the columns (i.e. D1 & D2, then I cant write the query as :

```
slect * from Table1
where ((C1,C2) NOT IN (Select (D1,D2) from Table2);
```

Can anyone help me rectify the above query?

Comment: Nicely structured question and exactly what i was struggling with

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t.* from Table1 t
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM Table2 t2
    WHERE t.C1 = t2.D1
    AND   t.C2 = t2.D2
)
```

Result:

```
C1  C2  C3
2   B   Y
3   C   X
```

Here's a Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/81fdd/4/0

`NOT EXISTS` has lesss isues than `NOT IN` anyway:

[Should I use NOT IN, OUTER APPLY, LEFT OUTER JOIN, EXCEPT, or NOT EXISTS?](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join)

Comment: your First `OR` needs to be `t.C1=t2.D1`

Comment: I afraid here the relation between C1 and C2 in a single row could not be maintained !!!

Comment: @Biki: I have edited my answer. Not sure if you referring to the first version. I've also added a demonstration. The row with `1   A   Z` is removed because there's a row `1   A` in the second table.

Comment: Thanks, your updated query works perfectly fine as per my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT T1.*
 FROM Table1 AS T1
 LEFT JOIN Table2 AS T2
   ON T2.D1 = T1.C1
  AND T2.D2 = T1.C2
WHERE T2.D1 IS NULL
```